# Is it correct to say "She married the rich man for her parents' wishes"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Most dictionaries have this kind of example, "**She married the poor man against her parents' wishes**".

However, as an English learner, I found it very strange that the dictionaries don't have an opposite expression.

For example, I expected the dictionaries would have an example like this "**She married the rich man for her parents' wishes**" because we know that "**for**" is the opposite of "**against**".

Is it correct to say "**She married the rich man for her parents' wishes**"?

Comment: "**She married the man of her parents' dream.**” would work but across different cultures it would not be interpreted in the same light.

Answer (score 3):

"*She married the rich man **according to** her parents' wishes.*"

This implies that she probably didn't want to marry the man herself.

It is not correct to use "for".

Answer (score 2):

> *She married the rich man* ***as her parents wished*.**

*For and against* is used in academic papers and controversial issues. It is similar to the concept of *pros and cons*, *advantages and disadvantages*.In the OP's scenario the marriage is not debatable.

*“She went **against** her parents wishes”* means she disagreed with their decision. *“She was ***for*** her parents wishes”* would be highly unusual and would be confusing for native speakers.

In English we would be more likely to say “She *[complied with](https://www.lexico.com/definition/comply)*…, *obeyed her* parents, *[acquiesced](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/acquiesce) to* the marriage,  or [*respected her parents' wishes*”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/respect-the-wishes-of)

Answer (score 1):

I think we would normally assume that the parents were happy about the marriage unless it is specified that they were not.

If the parents actually arranged or encouraged the marriage, there are various ways to say it. *Her parents found a rich husband for her - It was an arranged marriage - She married the man her parents had chosen for her* etc.